# Perl GetOptions() case sensitivity

Tags: perl, case-sensitive, getopt

```
GetOptions(
    "r|repo=s"       =>   \$repo,
    "R|list-repos"   =>   \$list,
);
```

When I call this script with `-r qwe` option, `$list` is updated to 1, which is not what I expect.

How can I make GetOpt case sensitive?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_ignore_case);
```

Answer (score 5):

Also enabling bundling fixes it too:

```
use Getopt::Long  qw(:config bundling);
```

From the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long#Bundling):

> When configured for bundling, single-character options are matched
> case sensitive while long options are matched case insensitive. To
> have the single-character options matched case insensitive as well,
> use:
>
> `Getopt::Long::Configure ("bundling", "ignorecase_always");`

And the author adds :

> It goes without saying that bundling can be quite confusing.